# Javascript version of showOptionDialog

Tags: javascript

Im wondering if there is a javascript function like java's showOptionDialog, where the user can chose between two different options in the dialog

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a `confirm` dialog that does exactly what you want.

You invoke it the same as you do for an `alert` or `prompt`.

Comment: it looks like crap but works perfectly, if you want a decent looking one you will need to use a thrid party js framework or create it yourself.

Comment: It looks however the browser developers want it to look. It's big plus is that it looks the same in every situation, rather than being completely different from site to site.